# How to update title of Sharepoint web using REST in c#

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, rest

I want to know how to update title of Sharepoint web using REST. I have used REST to view the title but not sure how to update the title.

I can view the title by exploring `http://urlofsite/_api/web/title` also.

MSDN has given the code in js but not in c#.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out by myself, this is how it will work. This is code is updating title of list, title of web can also be updated by changing the uri and post data.

```
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://sp2013vm/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tasks')");            
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    request.Headers["X-RequestDigest"] = getDigestValue();
    request.Headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";
    request.Headers["IF-MATCH"] = "*";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    request.Method = "POST";



    string stringData = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Title': 'New title' }";
    request.ContentLength = stringData.Length;
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
    writer.Write(stringData);
    writer.Flush();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: in a  similar way, how can i get a listitem that matches with a item name ? like if the listitem["title"] == "Employee" , i want to do some operations .

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use the Ahmed`s solution, I got the following error:

```
Exception calling "Flush" with "0" argument(s): "Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified." At C:\Scripts\UpdateItem.ps1:69 char:18
+     $writer.Flush <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I resolve this error by replacing this command

```
request.ContentLength = stringData.Length;
```

To this command

```
encoder = new UTF8Encoding(false)
request.ContentLength = encoder.GetByteCount(stringData)
```