# Update Document Library Title Using REST

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to update the Title of an existing document library using REST but getting this error

`The parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle.`

my REST endpoint is

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('RestTestLibrary')

and also tried

/_api/lists/getByTitle('RestTestLibrary')


Payload is

{
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.List"
},
"Title": "Rest Test Library"
}
```

headers are

[image]

Comment: Please check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54982/how-to-update-title-of-sharepoint-web-using-rest-in-c

Answer (score 0):

The rest api should be `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('RestTestLibrary')`.

This works for me, below is my test result. I'm using SharePoint Rest Client:

[image]

Also, you could refer to this:

https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/set-list-title-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api